# Im having problems with nested forms

Tags: php, database, forms

Hello im having some problems with my forms. It says "Saw a form start tag, but there was already an active form element. Nested forms are not allowed." but when im looking in my code the forms are not even nested in my code can i have some help.

```
    $sql8 = 'SELECT läggtill.serier, läggtill.id, läggtill.id2, läggtill.säsonger, läggtill.betyg, kategorier.kategori from läggtill inner join'
                . ' kategorier on läggtill.kategorier=kategorier.id order by läggtill.serier';

        $resultat8 = $mysqli->query($sql8);
        $antal8 = $resultat8->num_rows;

        while ($rad8 = $resultat8->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<li>" .$rad8['serier'] .', ' .$rad8['säsonger'] .' Säsonger, ' .$rad8['kategori'] .'<br>'.
                    'Betyg: ' .$rad8['betyg'] .'/10 </li>' .'<br>';
            $id = $rad8['id'];
            ?>
            <?php
            echo '<form action="alla.php" method="POST">
                <button name=' .$id .'>Ta bort</button>
            </form>'
            ?>
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST[$id])) {
                    $sql9 = "Delete from läggtill where id=" . $id . " LIMIT 1";
                    if ($resultat9 === $mysqli->query($sql9)) {
                        header('location: alla.php');
                    } else {
                        echo "det misslyckades.";
                    }
                    echo "asdasd";
                }    
                $id2 = $rad8['id2'];
                echo "<div class=" . 'Update' . '>'
                ?>

                <?php
            echo "<form action='alla.php' method='POST'>
                <label for='serier'>Serie: </label>
                <input type='text' name='serier' id='serier'><br>";

                $sql14 = 'SELECT * FROM kategorier';

                $resultat14 = $mysqli->query($sql14);
                $antal14 = $resultat14->num_rows;

                if ($antal14 == 0) {
                    echo 'Inget funnet';
                } else {
                    $sql15 = 'SELECT kategori, id FROM kategorier';
                    $resultat15 = $mysqli->query($sql15);
                    $antal15 = $resultat15->num_rows;

                    if ($antal15 == 0) {
                        echo 'Inget kategori funnen';
                    } else {
                        echo 'Kategori: <select name =kategorier>';
                        while ($rad15 = $resultat15->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo '<option value='. $rad15['id'] . '>' . $rad15['kategori'] . '</option><br>';
                        }
                        echo '</select>';
                    } 
                }


                echo '<br><button name= . $id2' . '>Uppdatera</button>';

                if (isset($_POST[$id2])) {
                    $kategorier = $_POST['kategorier'];
                    $betyg = $_POST['betyg'];
                    $serier = $_POST['serier'];
                    $säsonger = $_POST['säsonger'];

                    if(strlen($kategorier) && strlen($säsonger) && strlen($serier) && strlen($betyg)) {
                        $sql12 = '"UPDATE läggtill SET kategorier="" . $kategorier . "", säsonger="" . $säsonger . "", serier="" . $serier . "","
                                . " betyg="" . $betyg . "" WHERE id2="" . $id2 . "";';
                        if($resultat9 == $mysqli->query($sql12)) {
                            header('location: alla.php');
                        } else {
                            echo 'Det misslyckades';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            echo "</form>";
        echo "</div>";`**enter code here**`
```

Comment: The second `<form>` in your `while` loop is only closed outside of the loop.  So your HTML will look like this: `<form></form><form><form></form>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check have updated few things, hope it will work out

```
<?php
$sql8 = 'SELECT läggtill.serier, läggtill.id, läggtill.id2, läggtill.säsonger, läggtill.betyg, kategorier.kategori from läggtill inner join'
    . ' kategorier on läggtill.kategorier=kategorier.id order by läggtill.serier';

$resultat8 = $mysqli->query($sql8);
$antal8 = $resultat8->num_rows;

while ($rad8 = $resultat8->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<li>" . $rad8['serier'] . ', ' . $rad8['säsonger'] . ' Säsonger, ' . $rad8['kategori'] . '<br>' .
        'Betyg: ' . $rad8['betyg'] . '/10 </li>' . '<br>';
    $id = $rad8['id'];
    ?>
    <?php
    echo '<form action="alla.php" method="POST">
                <button name=' . $id . '>Ta bort</button>
            </form>'
    ?>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST[$id])) {
        $sql9 = "Delete from läggtill where id=" . $id . " LIMIT 1";
        if ($resultat9 === $mysqli->query($sql9)) {
            header('location: alla.php');
        } else {
            echo "det misslyckades.";
        }
        echo "asdasd";
    }
    $id2 = $rad8['id2'];
    echo "<div class=" . 'Update' . '>'
    ?>

    <?php
    echo "<form action='alla.php' method='POST'>
                <label for='serier'>Serie: </label>
                <input type='text' name='serier' id='serier'><br>";

    $sql14 = 'SELECT * FROM kategorier';

    $resultat14 = $mysqli->query($sql14);
    $antal14 = $resultat14->num_rows;

    if ($antal14 == 0) {
        echo 'Inget funnet';
    } else {
        $sql15 = 'SELECT kategori, id FROM kategorier';
        $resultat15 = $mysqli->query($sql15);
        $antal15 = $resultat15->num_rows;

        if ($antal15 == 0) {
            echo 'Inget kategori funnen';
        } else {
            echo 'Kategori: <select name =kategorier>';
            while ($rad15 = $resultat15->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<option value=' . $rad15['id'] . '>' . $rad15['kategori'] . '</option><br>';
            }
            echo '</select>';
        }
    }


    echo '<br><button name= . $id2' . '>Uppdatera</button></form>';

    if (isset($_POST[$id2])) {
        $kategorier = $_POST['kategorier'];
        $betyg = $_POST['betyg'];
        $serier = $_POST['serier'];
        $säsonger = $_POST['säsonger'];

        if (strlen($kategorier) && strlen($säsonger) && strlen($serier) && strlen($betyg)) {
            $sql12 = '"UPDATE läggtill SET kategorier="" . $kategorier . "", säsonger="" . $säsonger . "", serier="" . $serier . "","
                                . " betyg="" . $betyg . "" WHERE id2="" . $id2 . "";';
            if ($resultat9 == $mysqli->query($sql12)) {
                header('location: alla.php');
            } else {
                echo 'Det misslyckades';
            }
        }
    }
}

echo "</div>";
```